# using TCL expand in if statement

Tags: if-statement, tcl, expand, braces

I try to use an expand of a list of arguments ($options) in an if-statement in tcl

```
if {! [runCommandInRepo $componentpath git init {*}$options] } { exit 1 }
```

but I get an error saying there are "extra characters after close-brace"

How do you expand a list inside an if statement

Comment: can you post the entire error?  have you tried breaking this into multiple lines to pinpoint the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're using a very old version of Tcl there, probably 8.4 or before. The expansion syntax was added in Tcl 8.5. (8.4 is no longer supported, FYI.)

The “fix” is to use `eval` carefully:

```
if {! [eval [list runCommandInRepo $componentpath git init] [lrange $options 0 end]] } { exit 1 }
```

Yes, that is `eval [list …] [lrange … 0 end]`. That *guarantees* that everything is de-fanged of all possible failure modes (or at least that they'll reliably generate a nice error message telling you exactly what the problem is).

But really, ***upgrade*** please!

Comment: Ha! That explains why we didn't see this earlier. The error came from a user (client) who somehow got the error and indeed, he is still on 8.4 (I'm not ;-) ). Asked him to upgrade and we'll see what that gives. Thanks!!